# Javascript forcing array to behave like array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript arrays used to be just objects with some special syntax, but JIT engines can optimize the array to behave like a true array with O(1) access rather than O(log n) access. I am currently writing a   cpu intensive loop where I need to a certain I get O(1) access rather than O(log n). But the problem is that I may need to do array [5231] = obj1 right after its created but the array will eventually be filled. I am worried that such behaviour may trick the JIT to thinking that I am using it as a sparse array and thus I wouldnt get O(1) access time I require. My question is that is there ways I can tell or at least hint the javascript engine that I want a true array?

In particular, do I need to initialize the array with values first? Like fill all of it with reference to a dummy object (my array will only contain references to objects of same prototype or undefined). Would just set the array.length = 6000 be enough?

EDIT: based on http://jsperf.com/sparse-array-v-true-array, it seems filling the array beforehand is a good idea.

Comment: Maybe you should just write the program first using generally good algorithmic approaches to time-critical sections of code, and then start micro-optimizing if it's not fast enough and profiling suggests it might help.

Comment: Well, if you feel you need to create and fill an array, there's [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) for that very purpose (albeit ECMAScript 6).

Comment: I am asking if I need to do that not how to do that. And yes I have done the profiling.

Comment: So if you have done the the profiling didn't that tell you the answer?

Comment: Its hard to tell since I didnt do micro benchmarks but profiled the entire program as it run. I guess since its hard to tell that means I dont need to do it then, the js Engine is smart enough to figure it out. Or that it figure it out after the array is accessed for a while.

Comment: This would be a reasonable question had you not asked whether you "needed" to do this. Now it's opinion-based.

Comment: @simonzack Ok removed the edit. Now its factual?

Comment: The answer to your question relies on the javascript engine you're targeting.

Comment: @Sukima Don't post these snide comments if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @simonzack Apologies I didn't mean it to be snide. I was actually curious what the profiling result was. I presumed the result would provide the answer.

Comment: @Sukima Well I still dont know the answer to the question because although in the long run the JS engine will figure it out I still dont know how the cost of filling the array compares with the JS engine figuring it out. Both costs are not really measurable in the program as I just filled the array. It is a question of interest more on the theoretical side.

Comment: @simonzack - It's not opinion based. The question is basically saying "To achieve A do I need to do B?" which could be rephrased as "Can A be done without B?"

Comment: If you cant measure the costs its not worth pursuing as it will be different from engine to engine and may change with the next update of that bespoken engine...

Comment: @nnnnnn I did give an upvote after OP removed the opinion-based material.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I have made a big derp on my profiling test because it is an animation program with varying frame rate and my profiling was focused on detecting where the cpu intensive parts are. It was not suitable in comparing between the two methods as one method would simply run slower but the relative cpu time between different function calls would be the same.

Anyhow, I wrote a test on jspref: http://jsperf.com/sparse-array-v-true-array and (unless I made an error , which so, please do correct me!) A randomly accessed array without filling it first runs twice slower in Chrome and Firefox compared to filled version. So it seems that it is a good idea to fill it in first if you are writing things like a spatial hashmap.